# How do I recolor an image? (see images)

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, colors

How do I achieve this kind of color replacement programmatically?
[image: replacing black with blue]

---

So this is the function I have used to replace a pixel:

```
Color.FromArgb(
    oldColorInThisPixel.R + (byte)((1 - oldColorInThisPixel.R / 255.0) * colorToReplaceWith.R),
    oldColorInThisPixel.G + (byte)((1 - oldColorInThisPixel.G / 255.0) * colorToReplaceWith.G),
    oldColorInThisPixel.B + (byte)((1 - oldColorInThisPixel.B / 255.0) * colorToReplaceWith.B)
    )
```

Thank you, CodeInChaos!

Comment: Why did I lose an upvote, or get a downvote? lol...

Comment: No downvotes. I assume someone was able to remove their upvote when you edited the question. Either way, it's not something worth worrying about unless someone leaves a comment with a specific suggestion or criticism. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The formula for calculating the new pixel is:

```
newColor.R = OldColor;
newColor.G = OldColor;
newColor.B = 255;
```

Generalizing to arbitrary colors:

I assume you want to map white to white and black to that color. So the formula is `newColor = TargetColor + (White - TargetColor) * Input`

```
newColor.R = OldColor + (1 - oldColor / 255.0) * TargetColor.R;
newColor.G = OldColor + (1 - oldColor / 255.0) * TargetColor.G;
newColor.B = OldColor + (1 - oldColor / 255.0) * TargetColor.B;
```

And then just iterate over the pixels of the image(byte array) and write them to a new RGB array. There are many threads on how to copy an image into a byte array and manipulate it.

Comment: This answer looks the best to me, but that blue could be any color.

Comment: @Vercas Added formula for arbitrary colors.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I am testing the formula now. Plus, you forgot to add .R, .G and .B's to the "oldColor" variable.

Comment: This is probably the *simplest* solution, but iterating through a bitmap and modifying each pixel can be very slow, even if you use [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx). It depends on how many images you need to do this with, and how often.

Comment: I did not add them to the oldColor because I assumed the old color was just a byte, since the left image is just grayscale. And my code is only pseudo code. You should not use `Color` and `GetPixel` since that's *very* slow. You need to use something based on Bitmap.LockBits and perhaps copying to byte arrays.

Comment: I need to recolor just one image, when the program starts, so this is good enough!

Comment: @CodeInChaos the formula you gave is correct: `newColor=TargetColor+(White-TargetColor)*Input`.  But you made many mistakes in implementing it in code.  For example, for red, it should be: `newColor.R=TargetColor.R+(255.0-TargetColor.R/255)*InputColor.R;`.  Similar for other channels.

Comment: Well, after adding the .R, .G and .B's, I have tested it and it works perfectly! I have a 1 by 64 pixels image that needs to be recolored just once. :)

Comment: @misha 1) I assume that InputColor aka OldColor is just a byte since it's a grayscale image. 2) Your 255s are wrong in two ways. You're using integer division, so you map the target color to 0 unless it's 255. And replacing my 1 by 255.0 is wrong too. The only mistakes my pseudo-code has are that no sane Color struct would be mutable, and that my end result is double, and I assign it to a byte.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Whoops, I meant `newColor.R=TargetColor.R+(255.0-TargetColor.R)/255*InputColor.R`.  I was assuming newColor.R is in [ 0, 255 ] but now I see that it's [ 0, 1.0 ].

Comment: Recoloring multiple times makes the pixel more and more white

Answer (score 9):

Easiest would be to use **ColorMatrix** for processing images, you will even be able to process on fly preview of desired effect - this is how many color filters are made in graphic editing applications. [Here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial202_Using-the-ColorMatrix-in-Csharp.html) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Transformations0512192005050129AM/Transformations05.aspx) you can find introductions to color effects using Colormatrix in C#. By using ColorMatrix you can make colorizing filter like you want, as well as sepia, black/white, invert, range, luminosity, contrast, brightness, levels (by multi-pass) etc.

EDIT: Here is example (update - fixed color matrix to shift darker values into blue instead of previous zeroing other than blue parts - and - added 0.5f to blue because on picture above black is changed into 50% blue):

```
var cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
{
  new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  new float[] {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
  new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
  new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
  new float[] {0, 0, 0.5f, 0, 1}
});

var img = Image.FromFile("C:\\img.png");
var ia = new ImageAttributes();
ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);

var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);

gfx.DrawImage(img, rect, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);

bmp.Save("C:\\processed.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I might use a color matrix, but I have no idea what that is or how to use it for my purpose.

Comment: Example above does exactly what your example image conversion above.

Comment: You can experiment with values, in last row 3 values are adding RGB values (value from -1 to 1 means value from -255 to 255), on diagonal are multiplications of original RGB values (if you multiply/add too much, pixel value will be 0 or 255), near diagonal i've set 1 to shift values into blue. Experiment, it's worth it.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use a ColorMatrix here.  The source image is grayscale, all its R, G and B values are equal.  Then it is just a matter of replacing black with RGB = (0, 0, 255) for dark blue, white with RGB = (255, 255, 255) to get white.  The matrix thus can look like this:

```
1 0 0 0 0       // not changing red
0 1 0 0 0       // not changing green
0 0 0 0 0       // B = 0
0 0 0 1 0       // not changing alpha
0 0 1 0 1       // B = 255
```

This sample form reproduces the right side image:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Image mImage;
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        if (mImage != null) e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImage, Point.Empty);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (var srce = Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\grayscale.png")) {
            if (mImage != null) mImage.Dispose();
            mImage = new Bitmap(srce.Width, srce.Height);
            float[][] coeff = {
                            new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                            new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                            new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 }};
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(coeff);
            var ia = new ImageAttributes();
            ia.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(coeff));
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(mImage)) {
                gr.DrawImage(srce, new Rectangle(0, 0, mImage.Width, mImage.Height),
                    0, 0, mImage.Width, mImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
            }
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: That blue was just an example. The image to recolor can have any colors, not just grayscale and the color to replace/add could be any color, meaning that R, G and B can be anything. I do not understand this color matrices at all.

Comment: Well, then this is a just an example of how you use ColorMatrix to replace colors.  You'll have to come up with your own coefficients to do your own replacement.  Use this tutorial to get some insight in how it works: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/manipulate-visual-effects-with-the-colormatrixfilter-and-convolutionfilter/

Answer (score 3):

Depends a lot on what your image format is and what your final format is going to be.

Also depends on what tool you wanna use. 
You may use:

- GDI
- GD+
- Image Processing library such as OpenCV

GDI is quite fast but can be quite cumbersome. You need to change the palette.
GDI+ is exposed in .NET and can be slower but easier.
OpenCV is great but adds dependency.

---

**(UPDATE)**

This code changes the image to blue-scales instead of grey-scales - image format is 32 bit ARGB:

```
private static unsafe void ChangeColors(string imageFileName)
{
    const int noOfChannels = 4;
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(imageFileName);
    BitmapData data = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,img.Width, img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, img.PixelFormat);
    byte* ptr = (byte*) data.Scan0;
    for (int j = 0; j < data.Height; j++)
    {
        byte* scanPtr = ptr + (j * data.Stride);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Stride; i++, scanPtr++)
        {
            if (i % noOfChannels == 3)
            { 
                *scanPtr = 255;
                continue;
            }
            if (i % noOfChannels != 0)
            {
                *scanPtr = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    img.UnlockBits(data);
    img.Save(Path.Combine( Path.GetDirectoryName(imageFileName), "result.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Yes my friend but the ImageFormat is important. Is it 8bit grey-scale? 24bit WIndows Bitmap? 32bit having alpha? If you tell me which one you wanna use, I can give you the code example.

Comment: Well, I am opening a PNG image with no transparency, so I guess it is 24 bit.

Comment: As I commented on the accepted answer, that blue was just an example. It could be any color and my image can have more than white, it could have some red, too, for example.

Comment: Bearing in mind that your bytes are ordered as BGRA (and not ARGB) you can come up with all sorts of combinations. My code simply sets the Red and Green channel to zero and maximises the alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

This code project article covers this and more: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx

It uses the [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) library to do a Hue filter on an image for a similar effect:

```
  // create filter

  AForge.Imaging.Filters.HSLFiltering filter =
      new AForge.Imaging.Filters.HSLFiltering( );
  filter.Hue = new IntRange( 340, 20 );
  filter.UpdateHue = false;
  filter.UpdateLuminance = false;
  // apply the filter

  System.Drawing.Bitmap newImage = filter.Apply( image );
```

Comment: So, will this change any color in the range to my color?

Comment: I believe the library utilizes a hue range to allow for easy color substitution on images captured using a camera.  Think of green screen, the green isn't uniform in the image, but falls within a range depending on shadows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on what you want: do you want to keep the original and only adjust the way it is shown? An effect or pixelshader in WPF might do the trick and be very fast.

Comment: No, I need to adjust the original.

Answer (score -1):

If any Android devs end up looking at this, this is what I came up with to gray scale and tint an image using CodesInChaos's formula and the android graphics classes `ColorMatrix` and `ColorMatrixColorFilter`.

Thanks for the help!

```
public static ColorFilter getColorFilter(Context context) {
    final int tint = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tint);

    final float R = Color.red(tint);
    final float G = Color.green(tint);
    final float B = Color.blue(tint);

    final float Rs = R / 255;
    final float Gs = G / 255;
    final float Bs = B / 255;

    // resultColor = oldColor + (1 - oldColor/255) * tintColor
    final float[] colorTransform = {
            1, -Rs, 0, 0, R,
            1, -Gs, 0, 0, G,
            1, -Bs, 0, 0, B,
            0, 0, 0, 0.9f, 0};

    final ColorMatrix grayMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    grayMatrix.setSaturation(0f);
    grayMatrix.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(colorTransform));
    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(grayMatrix);
}
```

The `ColorFilter` can then be applied to an ImageView

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getColorFilter(imageView.getContext()));
```